# First-difference and lags

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I am newbie to time-series econometrics. I want to estimate a model for the association between greenhouse gas emissions and new green technologies. The estimation equation I want to use is $$CO_{t} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\ \ln GDP_{t}+\beta_{2} S_{t} + \beta_{2} F_{t}$$ where *CO* is emissions in a year, *GDP* is gross domestic product in a year,  *S* is the total amount of green technologies more than five years old and *F* is the total amount of green technologies from the last five years. (I measure green technologies in the number of green patents). I am uncertain about how to proceed. Several of these variables are non-stationary, so I must take care of that in one way or another. One possible approach is to use first-differences, but I am not sure how this would work when *S* and *F* are related the way they are (after five periods, everything that enters into *F* eventually ends up in *S*). Would a simple first difference approach work here?